# SQL Insert Multiple Rows Based On Variable

Tags: sql

I have a variable `@RowNumber`

I would like to create a variable table `@table` based on the `@RowNumber` variable.

If `@RowNumber` is 6 I would like the @table top present the following information

```
MonthID  Month
1        Month1
2        Month2
3        Month3
4        Month4
5        Month5
6        Month6
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated....

Comment: Solution will most likely depend on which **concrete database** system you're using; SQL is just the query language, not a database system. Please add whatever you're using as a tag to your question: `MySQL`, `DB2`, `Oracle`, `SQL Server`, `Postgres` or whatever else that might be ....

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (MonthID int, Month nvarchar(20))
DECLARE @RowNumber int = 12

DECLARE @Count int = 1
WHILE @Count <= @RowNumber
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Table (MonthID, Month) VALUES (@Count, 'Month' + CAST(@Count AS nvarchar))
    SET @Count = @Count + 1
END

SELECT * FROM @Table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @rownum int 
declare @monthid int
declare @date datetime

/* rownum initialized in your code*/
select @rownum = 6

select @monthid = 1
select @date = '20140101'

declare @table table ( 
MonthID int null,
MonthName varchar (10) null
);
while ( @rownum > 0 ) 
begin
insert into @table values ( @monthid , datename(month,dateadd(month,@monthid-1,@date)))
select @monthid = @monthid + 1
select @rownum = @rownum - 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

One way in SQL Server for a table `T`:

```
declare @RowNumber int = 6

;with T(MonthID, Month) as
(
    select 1 as MonthID , 'month' + cast(1 as varchar(6))
        union all
    select MonthID + 1, 'month' + cast(MonthID as varchar(6))
        from T
        where MonthID < @RowNumber
)

select * from T
```